# How to make a square shaped icon for ShortcutInfoCompat

Tags: android

I am trying to make a square-shaped shortcut like this

```
    IconCompat icon = IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(iconBitmap);

    return new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(context, Integer.toString(loyaltyCard.id))
            .setShortLabel(loyaltyCard.store)
            .setLongLabel(loyaltyCard.store)
            .setIntent(intent)
            .setIcon(icon);
```

But I always get a rounded shortcut no matter what image is passed. I guess I have to change IconCompat style somehow for it to be a square but how do I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: On modern versions of Android, the launcher app will choose the shape.

Comment: Hello, @CommonsWare, is there a way to override it? Also, is there reference to this information somewhere?

Comment: "is there a way to override it?" -- AFAIK, that would depend on the individual launcher. There are hundreds of those. "is there reference to this information somewhere" -- https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive among others.